# How to win break the blocks game when using 2d Array to represent blocks

Tags: xna, multidimensional-array

I am just learning XNA and started off my making a simple Break The Blocks Game. I am using a 2d array to represent the blocks at the top of the screen

```
    bricks = new Bricks[18,16];
        for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++)
        {               
            for(int x = 0; x < 18; x++)
            {
                bricks[x, y] = new Bricks(BrickTexture, new Rectangle(x * BrickTexture.Width, y * BrickTexture.Height, 38, 18), Color.Red);
                if (y == 2 || y == 3)
                {
                    bricks[x, y] = new Bricks(BrickTexture, new Rectangle(x * BrickTexture.Width, y * BrickTexture.Height, 38, 18), Color.Blue);
                }
                if (y == 4 || y == 5)
                {
                    bricks[x, y] = new Bricks(BrickTexture, new Rectangle(x * BrickTexture.Width, y * BrickTexture.Height, 38, 18), Color.Green);
                }
                if (y == 6 || y == 7)
                {
                    bricks[x, y] = new Bricks(BrickTexture, new Rectangle(x * BrickTexture.Width, y * BrickTexture.Height, 38, 18), Color.White);
                }
                if (y == 8 || y == 9)
                {
                    bricks[x, y] = new Bricks(BrickTexture, new Rectangle(x * BrickTexture.Width, y * BrickTexture.Height, 38, 18), Color.Pink);
                }
                if (y == 10 || y == 11)
                {
                    bricks[x, y] = new Bricks(BrickTexture, new Rectangle(x * BrickTexture.Width, y * BrickTexture.Height, 38, 18), Color.Purple);
                }
                if (y == 12 || y == 13)
                {
                    bricks[x, y] = new Bricks(BrickTexture, new Rectangle(x * BrickTexture.Width, y * BrickTexture.Height, 38, 18), Color.Navy);
                }
            }
        }
```

Thats how the blocks are built and they are draw with a foreeach loop to the screen.

```
    foreach (Bricks brick in bricks)
            {
                brick.Draw(spriteBatch);

            }
```

In my Update method I then use another for each loop to go through and check if the ball has collided with any of them and if they have to remove the brick from the screen. for for that and the collision method is as follows.

```
    foreach (Bricks brick in bricks)
            {
                brick.CheckBrickBallCollision(ball);

            } 

    public void CheckBrickBallCollision(Ball ball)
    {
        if (isVisible && ball.Ball2.Intersects(position))
        {
            isVisible = false;
            ball.direction.X *= 0.85f;
            ball.direction.Y *= -1;
        }
    }
```

My problem is how to make it so that once all the bricks are gone the game is won, and then by changing the game state would just come up with a won screen.

Any Ideas would be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this without really changing any code you can just count the number of visible bricks there are.

```
int visibleCount = 0;

foreach (Bricks brick in bricks)
{
    brick.CheckBrickBallCollision(ball);

    if (brick.isVisible)
    {
        visibleCount++;
    }
} 

//If there are no visible bricks then the player won!
if (visibleCount == 0)
{
    //Win the Game!
}
```

As another alternative, you could manage a list of active bricks versus managing their visibility. When a brick gets hit you could remove it from the list. When the list is empty then you know the player has won.

Comment: Those were the lines I was on at the min, but really doesnt like it, If you say put 288(the total number of bricks on the screen) it says you have won which is what you would expect however any other number it doesnt like, which would suggest its not adding any after the first time it runs that like, if you understand that?

Comment: When you debug are you sure that you end up inside the loop? You either have all your bricks visibility set to false or there are no bricks in your array resulting in visibleCount++ having no chance to get hit leaving visibleCount at 0. You need to make sure that these checks only happen while the player is actually able to win (Not during a game menu, not while the game is paused, only while the player is playing)

Comment: I posted what worked in the end, I cant see why that worked and yours didn't, But thanks for the Help put me on the right track works a dream now. Thanks Alot

Answer (score 0):

For some reason looking at the answer above this is what ended up working and thought i would share

```
    foreach (Bricks brick in bricks)
            {
                brick.CheckBrickBallCollision(ball);
                if (brick.isVisible == true)
                {
                    brokenBlocks -= 1;
                }                                     
            }
            if (brokenBlocks == 40)
            {
                currentGameState = GameState.Won;
            }
```